# Behavior of ElementTree iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I was initially confused about the behavior or `Element.__iter()__` and `ElementTree.__iter__()`.  It was unclear to me whether the iterator does a complete depth first traversal on *all* elements below it, or whether it only iterates over direct children.

The following test indicates it *only* iterates over direct children:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
>>> s = "<root><foo><bar></bar></foo><baz></baz></root>"
>>> t = etree.fromstring(s)
>>> for e in t: print(e)
... 
<Element 'foo' at 0x7ff15646a650>
<Element 'baz' at 0x7ff15646a6d0>
```

Note that `<bar>` was not included, because `<bar>` is a child of `<foo>`, not `<root>`.

Okay, fine... makes sense.

But the **[Python docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter)** say:

> iter(tag=None)
>
> Creates a tree iterator with the current element as the root. The
>   iterator iterates over this element and all elements below it, in
>   document (depth first) order. If tag is not None or '*', only elements
>   whose tag equals tag are returned from the iterator. If the tree
>   structure is modified during iteration, the result is undefined.

This wording, especially the phrase *"iterates over this element and all elements below it, in document (depth first) order"*, strongly, **strongly** implies to me that the documentation is saying that the iterator is supposed to iterate over *ALL* elements in the sub-tree, not just direct children.

Plus, the documentation also says "Creates a tree iterator with the **current element as the root**. The iterator iterates over **this element and** all elements below it" - indicating that the root element is supposed to be the first element returned in the iteration.  But in fact, the root element is not returned.  Instead, the first child is returned.

So, this documentation seems horribly misleading... and had me very confused.  Is the documentation simply wrong here, or am I just not interpreting what it's saying correctly?

Comment: You linked to the documentation for the Element class, not ElementTree.  [The docs for ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.iter) says "The iterator loops over all elements in this tree", which is somewhat more ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iter` that you are referring in the docs is different from the `__iter__` method.

To iterate over all the tags in depth-first order, use the `iter` method as below:

```
>>> for e in t.iter(): print(e)
... 
<Element 'root' at 0x10b92ccd0>
<Element 'foo' at 0x10b92cd10>
<Element 'bar' at 0x10b92cd50>
<Element 'baz' at 0x10b92ce10>
```

In contrast, `__iter__` will only iterate over direct children.